# Cancellling Out the Effect of Constant Gravitational Acceleration in a Datalogger

Tags: accelerometer, datalogger, gyroscope

In a design that records not only accelerometer readings (X + Y + Z) but also gyroscopic readings (X + Y + Z) how is it possible to remove the accelerometer readings caused by gravity?

I have found many datasets from [Crawdad](http://www.crawdad.org/) that provide better readings that are not effected by the said idle acceleration caused by gravity.

I have [prepared a data logger](https://amalindagamage.com/logger.php) to record the motion of a specific animal. In idle orientation I have noticed the z-axis is continuously recording 9.81ms^-2. I Would like to know if there is a method I can use to reduce the effect of this unwanted gravitational component. I only intend to record the acceleration caused by the animals movement. 
Any other suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: The most common methods are to localize it to an axis and filter with a high pass filter, or using a state estimator to keep track of the gravity vector and subtract it. Unfortunately a practical accelerometer can't measure the difference between being accelerated upward at 10m/s^2 or sitting on the ground.

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid here but if the accelerometer is not moving (held in a constant g-field) then you won't have an offset.

Comment: From what I understand, this is not an easy problem. You need to know which way is down (in the  coordinate system of your sensor), then subtract out 1g. But in order to know which way is down, you will likely need to process the data to generate an ongoing estimate of attitude (with respect to gravitational field), rate of rotation, and acceleration. Then you can subtract out the gravity component of acceleration. I think you should explain more about your application, though. There could be some "short cuts." Assumptions added to simplify the process.

Comment: If you don't want to say exactly what type of animal it is, at least say whether it is a slow moving animal, or if it rests frequently, does it ever turn upside down? Can it fly?

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you process logged data or real-time data the method  vary. What you need is presume that object is not constantly accelerating, which can be proved by the fact that animal stays on Earth.
You can use a moving average filter to subtract the mean value (gravitational bias) from each sample. You do this in Matlab by using filtfilt() which properly matches the initial and final state based on the data values. For filter you can design a simple averaging FIR filter with equal taps or some more suitable FIR filter. A good reason to use a filtfilt() is that it filters forth and back thus the filter delay is canccelled, all signals remain in exact phase.  You do the same with gyro, then fuse both data together.